# Cocos - How to create a Mac specific game (not iOS)

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am new to Cocos2d and followed the guide for creating a new game on GameFromScratch.com.

What terminal command do I use to create a system specific game such as for Mac or iOS? I'd rather do this so that I don't create a bloated game folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To run on mac machine, use 
`cocos run -p mac`. And
to create build for mac, first run command `cocos compile -p mac` and then go to the directory `cocos2d-x/build` and open and run the xcode project.

The detailed process is provided here
[cocos2d-x readme](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v4/README.md)